# gnuplot 5.4: dashtype if returns "expecting comma" error

Tags: if-statement, graph, gnuplot

I want to plot sets of tabulated data points with different line colors and dashtypes in gnuplot. Every set consists of 4 small ".csv" files, which shall be plottet in the same manor. Some of the sets are taken from a paper, others are my own simulated data.

I want the paper values to be black lines, but with different dash types and the simulated data to be solid lines, but with different colors. In the following "set" is a variable in a for loop, which is iterating over all specified sets. For linecolor the expression

```
lc ( set <= baseSets ? -1 : set )
```

works, but if I try the same for dash types, e.g.:

```
dt ( set <= baseSets ? set : 1 )
```

I get an error message saying "expecting comma" and pointing to "title":
[gnuplot error of dash if](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InaD4.png)

Why does "dt" take "set" as variable and every other number but with the if condition it breaks the code? The following link contains an archive with the script and different sets to plot.

[archive with gnuplot script and paper + simulated sets](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmhcyA9EuBmCtwm0vzil32JIGhNn?e=qAfAb6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `help dashtype`, you will see that there are three different notations for writing the dashtype option.

```
Syntax:
       dashtype N         # predefined dashtype invoked by number
       dashtype "pattern" # string containing a combination of the characters
                          # dot (.) hyphen (-) underscore(_) and space.
       dashtype (s1,e1,s2,e2,s3,e3,s4,e4) # dash pattern specified by 1 to 4
                          # numerical pairs <solid length>, <emptyspace length>
```

In your script, `dt ( set <= baseSets ? set : 1 )` is interpreted as the third notation because of the '(' character after dashtype.
After evaluation, this will be interpreted as `dt (anInteger)`.

In the third notation, even number of values separated by commas are expected, but you are only giving one. This is why the error message "expecting comma" is returned.

Try replacing it with `dt set <= baseSets ? set : 1` without parentheses.

Comment: or for clarity:    `dt int(set <= beseSets ? set : 1)`